# How to access my custom model located in catalog from system cart library in opencart 2.3

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-3, opencart-module, opencart2.3

I am adding this code via modification into system cart library to access my custom model located in catalog/model/extension/folder_name/file_name:

```
public function __construct($registry) {
global $loader;
$loader->model('extension/folder_name/file_name');
$this->model = $registry->get('model_extension_folder_name_file_name');
}
```

But it says:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function model() on null
in opencart 2.3.0.2

While this code is fine when I work on opencart 2.2.0.0.

Please help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you got the idea right, just a syntax error.

In OpenCart in a controller file the loader is accessed via `$this->load->model()`

But in system/library/cart/cart.php your code should look like this

```php
public function __construct($registry) {
    $registry->get('load')->model('extension/folder_name/file_name');
    $this->model = $registry->get('model_extension_folder_name_file_name');
}
```

> This is because you are accessing directly in system/library/cart/cart.php, where you have access to the `$registry` from the construct but no `__get()` and `__set()` functions like the controllers and models have.
>
> The cool thing is, the $this->load->model method actually checks where the cart is being called (is it from `catalog` folder or `admin` folder) and loads accordingly.
>
> You can be safe to load a model in `cart.php` because it is only called in `catalog` folder, but be careful adding such code to system/library/request.php which is loaded both in `catalog` and `admin`. this will creat errors.